# NGRok Mac OS Auto Logout

Tags: macos, terminal, localhost, macos-catalina, ngrok

I just installed ngrok for macos(i have the latest update), but every time i try to access it auto-logout. I'm guessing that it auto-logs out, but i'm not sure.[image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19K_PO3yeTht65LWpZimAdp9U1ziyx9XG/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run ngrok from the command line, not by clicking on it.

For example: `./path/to/ngrok http 80`